# How to remove actionbar shadow on Android version 21

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-styles

I can't remove the shadow below the actionbar, I already tried to use android:windowContentOverlay @null but it doesn't change a thing, I'm using API 21, how can I remove that shadow?

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>


</style>

<style name="Transparent" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Transparent</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

</style>
```

I also tried that:

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

NavigationDrawer:

```
public class NavigationMain extends ActionBarActivity implements Animation.AnimationListener {

    public int lastPosition = 0;
    private ListView listDrawer;
    private int counterItemDownloads;
    private DrawerLayout layoutDrawer;
    private LinearLayout linearDrawer;
    private RelativeLayout userDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggleCompat drawerToggle;
    private final int GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE = 200;
    private final int RESULT_CROP = 400;
    private NavigationAdapter navigationAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_main);


        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custombar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

        listDrawer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listDrawer);
        linearDrawer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearDrawer);
        layoutDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDrawer);

        userDrawer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.userDrawer);
        userDrawer.setOnClickListener(userOnClick);

        if (listDrawer != null) {
            navigationAdapter = NavigationList.getNavigationAdapter(this);
        }

        listDrawer.setAdapter(navigationAdapter);
        listDrawer.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggleCompat(this, layoutDrawer);
        layoutDrawer.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);


        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            setLastPosition(savedInstanceState.getInt(Constant.LAST_POSITION));

            navigationAdapter.resetarCheck();
            navigationAdapter.setChecked(lastPosition, true);

        } else {
            setLastPosition(lastPosition);
            setFragmentList(lastPosition);
        }


    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(Constant.LAST_POSITION, lastPosition);
    }

    private static final int REFRESH = 1;

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case Menus.HOME:
                if (layoutDrawer.isDrawerOpen(linearDrawer)) {
                    layoutDrawer.closeDrawer(linearDrawer);
                } else {
                    layoutDrawer.openDrawer(linearDrawer);
                }

            case REFRESH:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    public void setTitleActionBar(CharSequence informacao) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(informacao);
    }

    public void setSubtitleActionBar(CharSequence informacao) {
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(informacao);
    }

    public void setIconActionBar(int icon) {
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(icon);
    }

    public void setLastPosition(int posicao) {
        this.lastPosition = posicao;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }

    private class ActionBarDrawerToggleCompat extends ActionBarDrawerToggle {

        public ActionBarDrawerToggleCompat(Activity mActivity, DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout) {
            super(
                    mActivity,
                    mDrawerLayout,
                    R.drawable.ic_menu,
                    R.string.drawer_open,
                    R.string.drawer_close);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            navigationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int posicao, long id) {
            layoutDrawer.closeDrawer(linearDrawer);
            setLastPosition(posicao);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setFragmentList(lastPosition);
                }
            }, 350);
        }
    }

    private OnClickListener userOnClick = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            layoutDrawer.closeDrawer(linearDrawer);
        }
    };

    public void setFragmentList(int posicao) {

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = new InstituicoesActivity();

        switch (posicao) {

            case 0:
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                break;
//            case 1:
//                fragment = new MensagensFragment();
//                break;
//            case 2:
//                fragment = new EscolasFragment();
//                break;
//            case 3:
//                fragment = new AutorizadasFragment();
//                break;
//            case 4:
//                fragment = new CadastroFragment();
//                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            navigationAdapter.resetarCheck();
            navigationAdapter.setChecked(posicao, true);
            layoutDrawer.closeDrawer(linearDrawer);



    }


    public int getCounterItemDownloads() {
        return counterItemDownloads;
    }

    public void setCounterItemDownloads(int value) {
        this.counterItemDownloads = value;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem before and `android:windowContentOverlay = @null` didn't solve my problem.

But `setElevation(0)` method works. Just use it for your `Toolbar` or `AppBarLayout`.

For example:

`mAppBarLayout.setElevation(0);`

Comment: What is your XML file ? Did you use `setElevation` for toolbar or appbarlayout?

Comment: I had this problem before (i had a `Toolbar` inside a `AppbarLayout` ) by using `setElevetion` for `appbarlayout` it solves my problems. Just change your app theme to `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>` and then try `setElevation`

Comment: I have a navigation drawer and below it I have an FragmentTabHost, If I set  NoActionBar The app won't run, where is the appbarlayout?

Comment: AppBarLayout is a new concept in material design

Comment: Oh, I got it, but I'm not using it

Comment: I think it's better to change your way. using `Toolbar`, set your them to  `NoActionBar` ,extending your activity to `AppCompatActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity` most of these problems like shadows appear when you are using old concepts with new concepts. for example take a look at this example https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer didn't work for me.

To remove shadow in AppBarLayout use

`app:elevation="0"` in AppBarLayout xml or

use `mAppBarLayout.setTargetElevation(0)` in java.

I tried and it worked for me.